# PyQt: How to deal with QThread?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, pyqt4, signals-slots, qthread

In the following code I try to deal with `QThread`. In this executable example there are three buttons: first for start, second for stop and third for close. Well, when I start the task its runs like a charm. **BUT** when I want the while-loop to stop I click on the stop-button. And now, there is a problem: the while-loop doesn't stop.

You see, the stop-button emits a signal to call the `stop()` method on `TestTask()`.

What is wrong?

```
from sys import argv

from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QThread, Qt, QMutex

from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, \
     QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QTextEdit

class TestTask(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)

        self._mutex = QMutex()

        self._end_loop = True

    def init_object(self):
        while self._end_loop:
            print "Sratus", self._end_loop

    def stop(self):
        self._mutex.lock()
        self._end_loop = False
        self._mutex.unlock()

class Form(QDialog):
    stop_loop = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):


        self.pushButton_start_loop = QPushButton()
        self.pushButton_start_loop.setText("Start Loop") 

        self.pushButton_stop_loop = QPushButton()
        self.pushButton_stop_loop.setText("Stop Loop")       

        self.pushButton_close = QPushButton()
        self.pushButton_close.setText("Close")

        layout = QFormLayout()

        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_start_loop)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_stop_loop)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_close)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Tes Window")

        self.init_signal_slot_pushButton()

    def start_task(self):

         self.task_thread = QThread(self)
         self.task_thread.work = TestTask()
         self.task_thread.work.moveToThread(self.task_thread)
         self.task_thread.started.connect(self.task_thread.work.init_object)

         self.stop_loop.connect(self.task_thread.work.stop)

         self.task_thread.start()

    def stop_looping(self):
        self.stop_loop.emit()

    def init_signal_slot_pushButton(self):

        self.pushButton_start_loop.clicked.connect(self.start_task)

        self.pushButton_stop_loop.clicked.connect(self.stop_looping)

        self.pushButton_close.clicked.connect(self.close)



app = QApplication(argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stop_loop` signal is converted to an event and sent to the thread of the signal receiver. But your worker object is running a blocking while-loop, and this prevents the thread processing any pending events in its event-queue. So the slot connected to the `stop_loop` signal will never be called.

To work around this, you can call `processEvents` in the while-loop to allow the thread to process its pending events:

```
def init_object(self):
    while self._end_loop:
        QThread.sleep(1)
        QApplication.processEvents()
        print "Status", self._end_loop
```

Alternatively, you could call the worker's `stop()` method directly instead of emitting a signal. Strictly speaking, this is not thread-safe, but it would only be a problem if multiple threads could call `stop()` at the same time. So a more correct way to do that is to use a mutex to protect the value being changed:

```
class TestTask(QObject):   
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self._mutex = QtCore.QMutex()
        self._end_loop = True

    def stop(self):
        self._mutex.lock()
        self._end_loop = False
        self._mutex.unlock()
```

And now calling `stop()` directly from the main thread is thread-safe.

Comment: It seems the idia with QMutex()-class doesn't work. I have updated my code.

Comment: @Sophus. It does work, but as I said in my answer, you have to call `stop()` directly. So in `stop_looping` replace the emit with `self.task_thread.work.stop()`. Then the `stop_loop` signal is not needed at all.

Comment: @ ekhumoro: You were right. It does work. Thank you. Doesn't the data encapsulation be canceled, when I call the method directly?

Comment: @Sophus. That is what the mutex is for - it protects the `_end_loop` value (so calling `stop()` is thread-safe). Other than that, there is no difference.